# Vuejs route guard executes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to guard my routes via

```
routeritems.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
     auth.isLoggedin().then((res)=>{
       if(res.status){
         next({
           path: '/dashboard',
         })
       }else{
         next({
           path: '/auth/login',
           query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
          })
        }
    }, error=>{
       next({
        path: '/auth/login',
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
       })
    });

  } else {
     next() // make sure to always call next()!
  }
 })
```

in my auth i have

```
  isLoggedin() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Vue.http.post(authurls.is_loggedin, {permission: "is-guest"})
            .then(response => resolve(response.body), error=>reject(error))
            .catch(() => reject)
    });
}
```

But the above always results to an infinite http loop. Where am i going wrong?

UPDATE ON THE ROUTES

```
import authroutes from '@/components/frontend/auth/routes'
const routeritems = new Router({
  routes: [
    {path: '/auth', component: Auth,  meta: { requiresAuth: true }, children: authroutes},

   ]
 })
```

and the children authroutes i have

```
const authroutes = [
    {path: '', redirect: 'login'},
    {path: 'login', component: Login, name: "login" },
    {path: 'register', component: Register, name: "register" },
 ];

 export default authroutes;
```

Comment: Is the login success?

Comment: yes login status is success

Comment: What is the value for `res.status`?

Comment: it should be true or false

Comment: There are two chances to get infinite calls. If the `res.status` id false or the call is rejected/errored. Check for these two.

Comment: but even though that happens i have used an if statement with if(res.status) and also caught the promise error. So that should never be an issue.

Comment: Can u share `/auth/login` detail?

Comment: ive shared the routes as well

Comment: Make `requiresAuth` to false. It should work.

Comment: it still doesnt work.